# Vim Issue With Changing Color Schemes

Tags: vim, colors, iterm

I originally used the colorscheme Solarized Dark, which worked completely fine. I also used the correct iTerm2 theme to go along with it. Then, I made a switch to the Gruvbox colorscheme, and I switched to the GruvBox iTerm2 theme to go with that. This also worked fine.

My problem occurred when I attempted to switch back to the Solarized Dark color scheme. I would post images if I could, but here's what the relevant section of my `.vimrc` is:

```
set t_Co=256
syntax enable           " enable syntax processing
"Solarized Settings
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

These are the same settings I used when I first used the Solarized color scheme, and they worked fine.

But now, it looks like maybe the syntax colors are correct, but the background is pretty much black. And even if I add the let `g:solarized_transcolors=1` settings (which I never had to do before), which fixes the black background, the line number column, as well as buffer header (on top), also have black backgrounds.

Any insight into this issue would be appreciated. Note that I have also tried with a completely fresh `.vimrc` file and `.vim` folder, yet I still ran into the same problem, so I don't think this can be because of any conflicts among color schemes.

My suspicion is that the vim program is somehow storing old background colors it uses and prevents them from changing.

Comment: Solarized is the worst colorscheme ever written for Vim. Don't waste your time with that crap.

Comment: @romainl, which colorscheme do you suggest? I am in the process selecting one. Can you suggest a colourscheme

Comment: What does `:verb hi LineNr` say? I'm asking because these highlights are apparently not working (guessing from your description), and this command tells us what is the value set and where it was last set.

Comment: Recommend gruvbox for vim/nvim - https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox